# How to record incoming audio receiving in Headphone Programatically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Help me out to build a Javascript application to record incoming audio receiving in HeadPhone. I can record audio of my voice but not able to record other person voice that are coming in same headPhone

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript, running in a browser, has no means to intercept audio output from external sources.

To implement something like this (which is typicalled called a virtual audio device) you need a lower level program that can rejig how the OS treats audio (i.e. by diverting the audio output of one program into the virtual device (so the virtual device pretends to be a speaker) and then outputting it from the virtual device elsewhere (so the virtual device also pretends to be a microphone).

Comment: How the video call application able to record the audio & video of conference / meet ?

Comment: The audio and video data are sent to the application. It then outputs them to wherever it likes (including the user's speakers). It isn't picking up what is being send to the headphones, it has it already so it can send it to them.